# Why is earthdistance module not working in my Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a Postgresql (version 10) database, hosted on Amazon RDS. I was trying to experiment with the [earthdistance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/earthdistance.html) module - everything I read says that the module should be available, but the server is acting like it doesn't exist.

```
=> select earth_distance(ll_to_earth(42.1, 19.1), ll_to_earth(42.2, 19.2));
ERROR:  function ll_to_earth(numeric, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: select earth_distance(ll_to_earth(42.1, 19.1), ll_to_earth(4...
                              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


=> select ll_to_earth(42.1, 19.1) ;
ERROR:  function ll_to_earth(numeric, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: select ll_to_earth(42.1, 19.1) ;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


=> select earth() ;
ERROR:  function earth() does not exist
LINE 1: select earth() ;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I ran `SHOW rds.extensions`, and `earthdistance` does show up in the list. So what am I missing? Do I have to do something to activate this module?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `create extension earthdistance` in order to use it. Just because the binaries and scripts exist doesn't mean they are active.